# Inserting records in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

Any feedback will be appreciated.

I would like to insert the IP address, however the script is inserting the domain name instead of IP.

File name: file.txt

```
dns50.com: 1.1.1.1
dns51.com: 2.2.2.2
dns52.com: 3.3.3.3
```

Script:

```
for x in `cat /root/file.txt | cut -d: -f1` ; do 
    echo "ns1 14400 IN A $x" >> /var/named/$x.db
done
```

Inserted data when running the about script.

file: /var/named/dns50.com.db

```
ns1 14400 IN A dns50.com
```

file: /var/named/dns51.com.db

```
ns1 14400 IN A dns51.com
```

file: /var/named/dns52.com.db

```
ns1 14400 IN A dns52.com
```

But we would like to insert the following data

file: /var/named/dns50.com.db

```
ns1 14400 IN A 1.1.1.1
```

file: /var/named/dns51.com.db

```
ns1 14400 IN A 2.2.2.2
```

file: /var/named/dns52.com.db

```
ns1 14400 IN A 3.3.3.3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS=': ' read a b ; do  
    echo "ns1 14400 IN A $b" >> /var/named/${a}.db
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We were able to run it using the below mentioned command      # while IFS=': ' read a b ; do echo "ns1 14400 IN A $b" >> /var/named/${a}.db; done <file

Answer (score 1):

you can try this following awk command.

```
awk -F: '{print "ns1 14400 IN A "$2 > $1.db}' file.txt
```